# What's the difference between "continued fractions" and "compound fractions"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, fractions

What should we call a fraction which includes another fraction in its numerator or denominator, like $${ab\over {c \over d}}$$?

Comment: I don't know if there's a special name for it because it can be trivially simplified to $\frac{abd}{c}$.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia calls them [complex fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Complex_fractions), but notes that "compound fraction" is also used.

[Continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is a more specialized concept, which involves compounding in the denominator only, and in a particular way.